# ERR! code ELIFECYCLE - Error while executing TodoMVC

Tags: javascript, todomvc

I am trying to use TodoMVC for comparing performance of some JS frameworks.

I have done a clone of [online repository](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc),**`$ npm install`** inside main directory, the command **`$ gulp test-server`** is executed correctly (application started on http://localhost:8000/) but when i run **`$ npm run test`** it shows the following errors which i don't know how to solve

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzMZ2.png) -> this is solved

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezdKP.png) -> For the second error i have tried to do

1)npm cache clean --force

2)delete node_modules folder

3)delete package-lock.json

4)npm install

but is still shows the same error and can not run **$ npm run test**

Cypress installation error -> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndrny.png)

Answer (score 0):

The port 8000 is already in use, this is written black on white in the image you linked, first line of the error message, so you already have a server using that port. that's what EADDRINUSE means. Kill the process listening at 8000 or launch your tests on another address if possible.

Comment: ok thanks, i was running $ gulp test-server and  $ npm run test on the same time on two different terminals

Answer (score 0):

For your second error try to install `Cypress` globally:

```
sudo npm install -g cypress
```

And than try to run the test

Comment: thanks for the response.I tried to install globally but it shows that : Cypress cannot write to the cache directory due to file permissions(screenshot attached on question). I checked permission of /home/krisjana/.cache/Cypress but thay are drwxrwxrwx.

Comment: Try to `sudo npm run test`